# Spring Boot 2.x.x compatibility issue with hibernate 4.3.x

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am upgrading my spring boot version from 1.4.4 to 2.0.0 having hibernate version 4.3.11. But it looks like that spring boot 2.0.0 doesn't support hibernate version 4.x.x.

Initially, it gives me the entityManagerFactory error so I manually providede the entityManagerFactoryBean but after that, I am stuck with the following error

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy

Is there any workaround for this. I can't update my hibernate version for now because of some legacy code.

Comment: Spring Boot is kind of an umbrella project that defines dependencies and versions. It doesn't make sense to use an older version of a dependency.

Comment: Yup, it doesn't make sense but we have some code that creates dynamic hibernate entities and that's written on hibernate 4, I tried to upgrade to hibernate 5 but that requires a lot of code refactoring. We will re-write that code but for now, we just want to upgrade the spring boot version as we have some short time

Comment: And why don't us stay with Spring Boot 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrating from Spring Boot version 1 to version 2 is a big upgrade, you can check their [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide) as many things changed. We did a similar upgrade from 1.5 to 2.1 and it took us two weeks to complete it.

If you really must use Spring Boot 2 and Hibernate 4, you could always force exclude the new dependencies in your dependency manager, but that would (1) defeat the purpose of using newer version and (2) generate similar amount of work as if you were refactoring your code to support new version anyway